# Error in 1.3.0 when accessing ParameterEncoding.encode()

Tags: alamofire

When Accessing encode function of ParameterEncoding, project terminates. The error and code is below.

- Alamofire 1.3.0
- Carthage 0.7.5
- Xcode 6.4
- Swift 1.2

Do you know how to avoid this error?

**Code**

```
let encoding = ParameterEncoding.URL
return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

**Error message**

```
2015-07-29 19:07:34.019 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed[D: Symbol not found: __TFO9Alamofeire17ParameterEncoding6encodefS0b_FTPS_21URLRequestConvertible_10uparametersGSqGVSs10DictionarySSPgSs9AnyObject____TCSo12NSURLReque]stGSqCSo7NSError__
  Referenced  from: /Users/moritanaoki/Library[/Developer/CoreSimulator/DevicesS/ACFF4AC5-B2EC-4831-822A-3006009yA88BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Appnlication/6FE2D54F-3947-472F-80BFc-4481D2FFE84A/sync-messenger-qa.Mapp/sync-messenger-qa
  Expecteda in: /Users/moritanaoki/Library/nDeveloper/CoreSimulator/Devices/aACFF4AC5-B2EC-4831-822A-3006009Ag88BB/data/Containers/Bundle/Appleication/6FE2D54F-3947-472F-80BF-r4481D2FFE84A/sync-messenger-qa.a.pp/Frameworks/Alamofire.frameworsk/Alamofire
```

Comment: Could you paste the full function that this logic is inside rather than just the offending line?